# accordion with for loop to only open one item at a time

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I am trying to add an interactive id to my accordion, but something is off in my code and the accordion opens every accordion item, all I want is to be able to open one accordion item at a time when clicking on it.

```
    {% for study in studies %} <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
 <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{study.uid}">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
 data-bs- target="#collapse{study.uid}" aria-expanded="true" aria- 
controls="collapse{study.uid}">
            {{ study.uid }}
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapse{study.uid}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria- 
labelledby="heading{study.uid}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
            text
        </div> </div> </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your accordion elements are exactly the same, if you want the template to only show the first one then you can use `{{ forloop0.counter }}` to set different data for the nth accordion and hide the rest with whatever method you are using to toggle which accordion is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Thus formatted, your `For loop` creates as many `accordions` as there are `studies`.
Try to loop only on `accordion-item` as shown below :

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
{% for study in studies %}
 <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{study.uid}">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
 data-bs- target="#collapse{study.uid}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{study.uid}">
            {{ study.uid }}
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapse{study.uid}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{study.uid}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Also be sure to close all your `<div>`!

Comment: Hi, the problem is that all elements of the accordion are open at the same time still

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I don't have a django project on hand to confirm, but have you tried my snippet? Especially the remark about the divs... What was the result?